# Remove an element if it contains a specific word

Tags: javascript

I have a button that adds a specific word to a `<li>` in a `<ul>`.
There is also a button to have a `<li>` containing a specific word removed.

I really thought `includes()` or `match()` would work, but they aren't.

Below is a simplified version of my site. So `lastChild` or `removeChild` doesn't actually work in my case, despite being the obvious answer. This is because the `<li>` being removed may be in a random spot in the `<ul>`.

I also can't code the specific word like `includes(month)`. It needs to be `includes(WORD_BANK[0][0])`.

```js
const WORD_BANK = [
    ["day", "1"],
    ["month", "2"],
    ["year", "3"]
];

let counter = 0;

function addTo() {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += `<li>${WORD_BANK[counter][0]}<br>${WORD_BANK[counter][1]}</li>`;
    counter++;
}

function takeOut() {
    document.querySelector("li").innerHTML.includes(WORD_BANK[0][0]).remove();
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
<button id="add" onclick="addTo()">ADD</button>
<button id="remove" onclick="takeOut()">REMOVE</button>
```

Comment: `includes()` returns a Boolean. I think you need an `if` somewhere

Comment: This is a pretty odd design. `addTo()` crashes after being clicked 3 times and `takeOut()` crashes when the list is empty. I wouldn't use inline `onclick`. Chaining `.includes(WORD_BANK[0][0]).remove()` doesn't work. `remove()` needs to be called on a DOM node. You may have oversimplified the design for the purposes of the question here.

Comment: if you want to remove the `li`s in the same order they were added you can try `document.querySelector("li").remove()`. would that solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need `querySelectAll` to get all `li` elements, and you need to use `find` method to find the `li` which `includes` the text.

```js
const WORD_BANK = [
    ["day", "1"],
    ["month", "2"],
    ["year", "3"]
];

let counter = 0;

function addTo() {
    if (counter >= 3) {
      console.log('All array has been added');
      return
    };
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += `<li>${WORD_BANK[counter][0]}<br>${WORD_BANK[counter][1]}</li>`;
    counter++;
}

function takeOut() {
    const element = [...document.querySelectorAll("li")].find(li => li.textContent.includes(WORD_BANK[counter - 1][0]))
    if (element) {
      element.remove()
      --counter;
    } else {
      console.log('element not exist')
    }
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
<button id="add" onclick="addTo()">ADD</button>
<button id="remove" onclick="takeOut()">REMOVE</button>
```

Comment: Add crashes after 3 clicks

Answer (score 0):

```js
const WORD_BANK = [
  ["day", "1"],
  ["month", "2"],
  ["year", "3"]
];

let counter = 0;

function addTo() {
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += `<li>${WORD_BANK[counter][0]}<br>${WORD_BANK[counter][1]}</li>`;
  counter++;
}

function takeOut() {
  const ele = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  if (ele.length > 0) {
    ele[counter - 1].remove();
    counter--;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
<button id="add" onclick="addTo()">ADD</button>
<button id="remove" onclick="takeOut()">REMOVE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do with includes then:

```js
const WORD_BANK = [
  ["day", "1"],
  ["month", "2"],
  ["year", "3"]
];

let counter = 0;

function addTo() {
  if (counter > WORD_BANK.length - 1) return; // check
  document.getElementById(
    "list"
  ).innerHTML += `<li>${WORD_BANK[counter][0]}<br>${WORD_BANK[counter][1]}</li>`;
  counter++;
}

function takeOut() {
  if (counter < 1) return; // check
  --counter;
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("li"))
    .find((e) => e.innerHTML.includes(WORD_BANK[counter][0]))
    .remove();
}
```

```html
    <ul id="list"></ul>
    <button id="add" onclick="addTo()">ADD</button>
    <button id="remove" onclick="takeOut()">REMOVE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need neither `includes` or `match` if you are going to remove elements without any specific order.

Here's an error free version of your desired outcome I guess:

```js
const WORD_BANK = [
  ["day", "1"],
  ["month", "2"],
  ["year", "3"],
];

let counter = 0;

function addTo() {
  const list = document.getElementById("list");

  if (counter < WORD_BANK.length) {
    const liMock = `<li>${WORD_BANK[counter][0]}<br>${WORD_BANK[counter][1]}</li>`;

    list.innerHTML += liMock;
    counter++;
  }
}

function takeOut() {
  const li = document.querySelector("li");
  if (li) {
    li.remove();
    counter--;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
    <button id="add" onclick="addTo()">ADD</button>
    <button id="remove" onclick="takeOut()">REMOVE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```js
const WORD_BANK = [
  ["day", "1"],
  ["month", "2"],
  ["year", "3"]
];

let counter = 0;

function addTo() {
  counter = counter % WORD_BANK.length; // for avoiding index out of range error
  const node = document.createElement("li");
  const textnode = document.createTextNode(`${WORD_BANK[counter][1]} - ${WORD_BANK[counter][0]}`);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(node);
  counter = counter % WORD_BANK.length + 1;
}

function takeOut() {
    const list = document.getElementById("list");
    if (list.hasChildNodes()) {
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(list.children)) {
        if(value.textContent.includes(WORD_BANK[0][0])) {
        list.removeChild(list.children[key]);
      }
   }
}
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
<button id="add" onclick="addTo();">ADD</button>
<button id="remove" onclick="takeOut();">REMOVE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

problem with your `takeOut` function in you use `includes` which return boolean not an dom element so it cause error.
**we use two way to remove childs.**

1. if you want to remove last child by accessing `lastChild` key in selected element object.
2. by check innerText value against your `WORD_BANK[0][0]` in selected element

```js
const WORD_BANK = [
  ["day", "1"],
  ["month", "2"],
  ["year", "3"]
];

let counter = 0;

function addTo() {
  if (counter < 3) {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += `<li>${WORD_BANK[counter][0]}<br>${WORD_BANK[counter][1]}</li>`;
    counter++;
  }
}

function takeOut() {
  // if want to remove last child li
  // if (counter > 0 && counter <= 3) {
  //   document.getElementById("list").lastChild.remove();
  // counter--;
  // }

  // if you want to remove by innerText key of li
  const dj = document.getElementById("list")?.children;
  Object.keys(dj).forEach(e => {
    if(dj[e]?.innerText?.includes(WORD_BANK[0][0])) {
      dj[e].remove();
      counter--;
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
  <button id="add" onclick="addTo()">ADD</button>
  <button id="remove" onclick="takeOut()">REMOVE</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
let WORD_BANK = [
            ["day", "1"],
            ["month", "2"],
            ["year", "3"]
        ];

        let counter = 0;

        let listData

        function addTo() {
            document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += `<li>${WORD_BANK[counter][0]}<br>${WORD_BANK[counter][1]}</li>`;
            counter++;
        }

        function takeOut() {
            const list = document.getElementById("list")
            list.removeChild(list.firstElementChild);
        }
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    </ul>
    <button id="add" onclick="addTo()">ADD</button>
    <button id="remove" onclick="takeOut()">REMOVE</button>
```